# LINQ or Lamba to sort an array of integers in ascending order within the set of their frequency of repetition

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

my input is as below

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9, 7, 7, 7};
```

as seen,

```
3,1,4 are repeated only 1 time
2, 6 are repeated 2 times each
9, 7 are repeated 3 times each.
```

how to write logic to sort array in such a way that they are in ascending order within the sets which are in their frequency of occurrence

Expected Output for above array is
    `1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9`

My Try:

```
var res = (arr.OrderBy(i => i).Reverse()
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .Where(g => g.Count() >= 1)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Count())
            .Select(x => x) // stuck here
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: Is there any spec that limits you to only use LINQ and not a traditional for loop that  it can make your try easier??

Comment: @apomene: traditional loop also would do but using LINQ or Lambda is preferred

Comment: You shouldn't Order items you are grouping. And order them on `Count` `ThenBy` value.  `SelectMany` is the key to flatten a two level object tree

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @un-lucky: Expected output is  1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var result = arr.GroupBy(x => x)
                .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
                .ThenBy(g => g.Key)
                .SelectMany(g => g);
```

This will group the elements, sort first by the number of elements (ascending) then by the element value and finally flatten into an enumerable.

Comment: Thanks, thats correct, I never expected it to be so simple. :)